# linear transformation & normed space

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^2 →\mathbb{R}^3$ be such that $g(0)=(1,1,1)$ and
$
   [Dg(0)]=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \     \\1 & 1 \\1& 1 \      \end{array} } \right]
$

Find $D_\mathbf{0}(\|g\|)(\mathbf{h})$ and $[D_\mathbf{0}(\|g\|)]$, where $\|·\| =  \sqrt{⟨·, ·⟩}$ is the standard norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I basically do not know how to start this problem. Can anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the chain rule:

$$D_0(\|g\|) = D_{g(0)}(\|\cdot\|) \circ D_0(g)$$

Hence:

$$[D_0(\|g\|)] = [D_{(1,1,1)} (\|\cdot\|)][D_0(g)]$$

Now recall that $D_x (\|\cdot\| )= \frac1{\|x\|} \langle x, \cdot \rangle $. Hence, $D_{(1,1,1)}(\|\cdot\|) h= \frac1{\sqrt 3} (h_1 + h_2 + h_3)$, which shows that:

$$[D_{(1,1,1)}(\|\cdot\|)] = \frac1{\sqrt 3}(1,1,1)$$

Therefore,

$$[D_0(\|g\|)] = \frac1{\sqrt 3} (1,1,1) \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 &1 \\ 1 &1 \end{pmatrix} = \sqrt 3 (1,1)$$